# how to modify or generate code in kotlin? (not only JVM)

Tags: java, kotlin

How can I generate or modify exiting code in Kotlin at compile time?

in JVM there is an option (`kapt`) to generate code based on annotations,  but that's not great for Kotlin because it's work on JVM's byte code and have some difficulties with Kotlin types (as we know Kotlin provides it's type specifications in `@Metadata` annotation in JVM)
I need a way to do this even if I'm not on JVM environment for supporting Multiplatform projects

I know that Kotlin `official serialization library` doing that ,But I don't know how.
for example if you annotate a class with `@Serializable` but
don't provide a serializer in companion object, compiler will create a serializer on that class companion object automatically at compile time.
or even `Dagger hilt` during compile time ,modifies all annotated activities to extend its custom Activity class for injection purpose.
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If you want to generate additional code on existing declarations, this should be possible via a compiler plugin, however this API is not stable and I don't believe it's documented anywhere at the moment. If you want to just generate code, you can use stuff like Kotlin Poet

Comment: Kotlin Poet is great but I need a way to create code based on annotations and kotlin types  can't be represented nicely by java annotation processor

Comment: Maybe [Kotlin Symbol Processing API](https://github.com/google/ksp) can help you, however it's still in unstable/preview stage.

Comment: I think https://github.com/Foso/MpApt can help you